# Why is my karma tests runs without angular application?

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I've downloaded angular+karma+jasmine project from the internet, and when i run "ng test" it looks like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g566.png)

But when i create my own project in angular, and write "ng test" it looks like this [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGnsY.png)

What am i missing? My app only shows in browser on "ng serve" but when i run "ng test" i see only tests without the app, how do i make my app show with karma interface like in downloaded project?